# Can I use Mongo DB to setup a server to develop with three.js library?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm a student of the Miami Dade Collge working in a small project I can't find info about this any help is welcome, thanks

Comment: Can you please clarify your question a little more? Three.js is a library for making 3d graphics/visualizations in the browser, and MongoDB is a server side database used for storing data in a JSON like format.

Comment: you basically answer my question